# how to write manual south migration for a newly added custom field

Tags: django, django-models, django-south

**This is my newly added field to my quote model

```
quote_template = models.CharField(_('Template'), choices=TEMPLATE, max_length=20)
```

at sudo ../hatsenv/bin/python manage.py schemamigration quote --auto

I am getting this error

! Cannot freeze field 'quote.quote.tags'

! (this field has class tags.managers.PartnerTaggableManager)

! South cannot introspect some fields; this is probably because they are custom

! fields. If they worked in 0.6 or below, this is because we have removed the

! models parser (it often broke things).

! To fix this, read http://south.aeracode.org/wiki/MyFieldsDontWork

how to write manual migration for this one**

Comment: Why won't a regular schemamigration work for you?

Comment: Have you tried the advice in the MyFieldsDontWork page? You'll find that adding the introspection rule or the South Field Triple is actually pretty straightforward, with the docs provided

Comment: I have tried south_field_triple method and extend South’s introspection rules but that does not work I think I have to write manual migrations

Comment: If you can't generate a migration, a manual migration will fail too. You have to fix the problem. Also, why are you using sudo for a schemamigration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ignore the field at time of migration

from south.modelsinspector import add_ignored_fields

add_ignored_fields(["^taggit.managers"])